# Sort data into multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I sort data from a DataFrame into a DataFrame that uses a MultiIndex for both the indices and columns?

For example, convert from this:

```
     0    1  2     3     4
0  foo  two  A  2.30  0.01
1  foo  one  A  4.12  0.13
2  bar  two  B  9.89  3.66
3  foo  one  A  2.11  9.48
4  bar  two  A  1.07  5.55
```

to this:

```
            A           B      
            1     2     1     2
foo one  2.11  9.48   NaN   NaN
    two   2.3  0.01   NaN   NaN
bar one   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    two  1.07  5.55  9.89  3.66
```

Currently I am iterating over each row in `df1` and updating the values in `df2`, but I'd like a more efficient method than this:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2.loc[(row[0], row[1]), row[2]] = list(row[3:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a':x.values.ravel()}).rename(lambda x: x + 1)

df = df.groupby([0,1,2])[3,4].apply(f)['a'].unstack([2,3]).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
df = df.rename_axis((None, None),axis=1).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))
print (df)
            A                       B      
            1     2     3     4     1     2
bar one   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    two  1.07  5.55   NaN   NaN  9.89  3.66
foo one  4.12  0.13  2.11  9.48   NaN   NaN
    two  2.30  0.01   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. For each group by first 3 columns [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) custom function with `DataFrame`, also increment index value for start from `1`
2. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and sort `Multiindex` in columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
3. Remove columns names (`2` in left corner) and add missing catagories to `MultiIndex` in index by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

Comment: Could you briefly explain how this works to speed up performance?

Comment: @user2970608 - Not sure if understand, last `explanation` is not enough?

Comment: I mean why this is faster

Comment: @user2970608 - Because `iterrows` is obviously very rare used, because very slow - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316).